# Maximize $4x_1+x_2+3x_3$

Tags: maximum-principle

Maximize $4x_1+x_2+3x_3$ given the constraint $x_1+x_2+x_3=x$, I used lagrange multiplier and it gave me 3 different values of $\lambda$, what does this indicate?

Comment: Do you have other constraints on $x_i$'s (for instance non-negativity)? Else the maximum is $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, $x_1,x_2,x_3 $are non-negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I see is as follows. We have
$$4x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 = 4(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) - 3x_2 - x_3 = 4x - 3x_2 - x_3$$
Since $x_2,x_3 \geq 0$, we have $ - 3x_2 - x_3 \leq 0$, which gives us
$$4x - 3x_2 - x_3 \leq 4x$$Equality holding when $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = x_3 = 0$.

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense, but can you help me with the lagrange method?